# Problem with scatter plot legend using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, legend, scatter-plot

I am having a problem with my legend formatting, when using matpotlib to create a scatter graph. In this case, the data itself is being plotted correctly on the scatter graph, but the legend has incorrect values.

As you can see from the attached graph - the hotend temperature data is in the form 175ºC, 185ºC, 195ºC, 205ºC..., but the legend is displaying rounded-up values (180, 190, 200, 210...).

The legend also has 10 entries when there should be 11 (175ºC - 275ºC at intervals of 10).

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Code snippet for reference:

```
    fig, ax3 = plt.subplots()

    x = comb_df['level']
    y = comb_df['max_force']
    
    scatter = ax3.scatter(x,y,c=x)
    ax3.set_xlabel('{}'.format(varcap) + " ({})".format(unit))
    ax3.set_ylabel('Max Force (N)')
    
    # Plot trendline
    x = comb_df['level']
    y = comb_df['max_force']
    
    tline = np.polyfit(x,y, 2)
    p = np.poly1d(tline)
    ax3.plot(x, p(x), "r--", alpha = 0.5)

    # Shrink current axis by 20%
    box = ax3.get_position()
    ax3.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

    # Set custom tick labels if tempaerature is being plotted
    if var == "hotend_temp":
        ax3.set_xticks([175,195,215,235,255,275])
    
    ax3.set(ylim=(50, 101))
    plt.title('{} - Max Force Scatter Plot'.format(varcap))
    
    handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements()
    legend = ax3.legend(handles, labels, title="{}".format(varcap),loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02 , 0.5))
```

Produced graph:
[Hotend Temperature vs. Max Force Scatter Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rpHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the line that you should check/change is : `handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements()`

the function `legend_elements()` has a parameter called `num` which adjusts the number of entries you want your legend to have, you can check the doc [Here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements)

Answer (score 0):

If you print the `handles` in your code, you will see that there are only 10 entries. For some reason, the default is set to 10. Changing this to 9 or 11 will not change it. Increasing beyond will give you numbers like 176,184, etc. Instead, replace the `scatter.legend_elements()` to have number of `None`. This will make it use all unique elements. So, use this instead of what you have...

```
handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop='colors', num=None)
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Note: I have used random x and commented out the varcap related lines.